# Not able to click on single button when there are multiple buttons with same XPATH

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, selector

I am trying to click on Button, but not able to click due to having same xpath's for all buttons on the webpage.

There are Questions with Yes and No option button. I want to identify the button with question.

All the Yes button are of same XPATH and all the No buttons are of same xpath.

Below is the HTML code to click on "Yes" button :

```
<div id="answerContainer_id" class="right two answerContainer">
<input id="validation_question_3_13" type="hidden" value="required"   
name="validation_question_3_13"/>
<div class="answer questionAnsleft selected">
<input id="answer_3_13_1" type="radio" value="1" name="Q13" style="display:none;"/>
<div class="questionAnsRight">                                                                 
Yes                                                            </div>
</div>
<div class="answer questionAnsleft disabled">
</div>
</div>
<div id="question_3_14" class="">
<input type="hidden" name="questionIds[]" value="14"/>
<div class="left" style="width: 680px;">
<div id="answerContainer_id" class="right two answerContainer">
<input id="validation_question_3_14" type="hidden" value="required"   
 name="validation_question_3_14"/>
<div class="answer questionAnsleft selected">
<input id="answer_3_14_1" type="radio" value="1" name="Q14" style="display:none;"/>
<div class="questionAnsRight">                                                                 
 Yes                                                            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using xPath you can uniquely identify needed element. Try to use indexes to access needed element (e.g. div[1]). Is everything ok with html? Some div elements have no closing tags

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do your input tags have `type="hidden"` or `style="display:none;"`?  These hide your radio buttons / inputs so they can't be clicked.

Comment: @olyv Can you please tell me how to use indexes to identify element.

Comment: Refer to Ram's answer and the xpath you wrote //*[@id='answerContainer_id']/div[i]. That's what I meant. And if you want to click all buttons one by one then put your expression into loop and change 'i' from 1 to 5 (number of buttons).

Comment: I can't use loop because I have to verify each question for multiple Question Set and there is very huge data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind button to answer input

For first button css

```
#answer_3_13_1+div
```

For second

```
#answer_3_14_1+div
```

Or use name

- `[name=Q13]+div`
- `[name=Q14]+div`

Comment: I have tried for both xpath as per your suggestion. But it is still not able to click on the element.

Comment: Please, provide your code. And get more information about error (may be, make video and post it)

Comment: I am using data-driven framework, so there is no script. I can't post even video also.

Comment: I have tried for: answer_3_13_1+div and [name=Q13]+div. It is working.Thanks a LOT.

Answer (score 1):

I dont even know how many questions are there in your page..    But as per your HTML source, there are two questions and two yes buttons. You can use the xpath as (xpath=//div[@class='questionAnsRight'])[1]. 
If you need to click more number of Yes buttons, iterate it with (xpath=//div[@class='questionAnsRight'])[i].

Comment: There are 5 questions. I have tried for this xpath "//div[@class='questionAnsRight'])[1]" not able to identify element.

Comment: To click all the Yes Button, I have used this xpath : //*[@id='answerContainer_id']/div[2] and it is working. But I want to click one by one buttons.

Comment: In my Projectd i have used the similar xpaths as below, 
`private String CONTENT_TYPE_SEARCH_LOC = "xpath=(//input[@name='attrType.contentTypeId'])[2]";
private String CONTENT_TYPE_SITE_LOC = "xpath=(//input[@name='attrType.contentTypeId'])[3]";    Then use the selenium command as selenium.type(CONTENT_TYPE_SITE_LOC,"test");`

Comment: I have used for the xpath   =  //input[@id='answer_3_13_1']/following-sibling::div[1]/./text(). Element is able to identify but I am not able to click on Button. Please let me know whether the xpath is correct or not.